# Can't initialize constant in Swift Structure while handling initialization errors

Tags: swift, swift2

Title is pretty self explanatory. Here's the code:

```
struct APIConnection {

enum APIConnectionError: ErrorType {

    case InvalidRegion(invalidRegion:String)
}


let validRegions:Set<String> = ["na","eune","euw","kr","lan","las","br","oce","ru"]

let apiKey:String, region:String
var url:NSURL!

init(region:String,apiKey:String) {

    func setRegion() throws {

        if self.validRegions.contains(region) { self.region = region } // Can't assing since region is a let constant
        else { throw APIConnectionError.InvalidRegion(invalidRegion: region) }
    }

        do { try setRegion() } /* If I change region to a var, compiler says setRegion() utilizes a yet non-initialized
            apiKey constant. */
        catch APIConnectionError.InvalidRegion(let invalidRegion) { print("Invalid region: \(invalidRegion)") }
        catch let unknownError { print("Unknown error: \(unknownError)") }
}

}
```

- I can't finish the initializer properly, since it won't assign self.region to the initializer's region constant inside the setRegion function.
- apiKey also produces me a strange bug: It apparently is copied when I execute the setRegion function, not allowing the latter to be executed since it hasn't been initialized yet; though I didn't use it anywhere in my code yet.

Edit: Rewrote this part of the code:

```
 func isRegionValid(region:String) throws -> Bool{

            if self.validRegions.contains(region) { return true } // Can't assing since region is a let constant
            else { throw APIConnectionError.InvalidRegion(invalidRegion: region) }
        }

        do { if try isRegionValid(region) { self.region = region } }
```

However, I still get an error saying the closure 'setRegion()' is capturing api-key's value, and I don't know why.

Comment: I think that you pasted your code incorrectly, because you have a function declaration inside your initializer.

Comment: I guess that because your assignment is not directly in init(), the usual rules about assigning to constants doesn't apply.

Comment: Isn't init() a closure though? As far as I am aware, I can nest a closure inside another closure. 

Please, correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: So, I need to set the constant inside the init then? Not inside any other kind of method/enclosure?

Comment: Just edited. If I declare apiKey's value before handling the region type, the code seems to compile with no issues.

However, I still am unsure why this happens, and, most importantly: **Is setting apiKey's value first a good idea, or is it bad coding practice?**